# How to print next line in python

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, file-io, filestream

I am trying to print next 3 lines after a match

for example input is :

```
Testing
Result
test1 : 12345
test2 : 23453
test3 : 2345454
```

so i am trying to search **"Result"** string in file and print next 3 lines from it:

**Output will be :-**

```
test1 : 12345
test2 : 23453
test3 : 2345454
```

my code is :

```
with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line
        if "Benchmark Results" in f:
            print f
            print next(f)
```

its only giving me the output :

```
testing
```

how do i get my desired output, help please

Comment: The line 

if "Benchmark Results" in f

does not appear to capture your desired conditions.  I think you want something more like 

if "Result" in line 

instead.

Comment: @GrumbleSnatch The test of "Benchmark Results" is wrong because it is being tested against "f" and not "line".

Comment: @Shield-pro: while formatting your input and output, I have removed the blank lines. Please re-add them if they are really part of your input/output

Answer (score 5):

First you need to check that the text is in the `line` (not in the fileobj `f`), and you can utilise `islice` to take the next 3 lines from `f` and print them, eg:

```
from itertools import islice

with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'Result' in line:
            print(''.join(islice(f, 3)))
```

The loop will continue from the line after the three printed. If you don't want that - put a `break` inside the `if`.

Comment: This is clever. I have to admit I never use `islice` and I probably should. Now that I've seen this I definitely like it better than my answer below :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest opening the file and spliting its content in lines, assigning the outcome to a variable so you can manipulate the data more comfortably:

```
file = open("test.txt").read().splitlines()
```

Then you can just check which line contains the string "Result", and print the three following lines:

```
for index, line in enumerate(file):
    if "Result" in line:
        print(file[index+1:index+4])
```

Answer (score 1):

You are testing (and printing) "f" instead of "line". Be careful about that. 'f' is the file pointer, line has your data.

```
  with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
      line = f.readline()
      while(line):
          if "Benchmark Results" in line:
               # Current line matches, print next 3 lines
               print(f.readline(),end="")
               print(f.readline(),end="")
               print(f.readline(),end="")
          line = f.readline()
```

Comment: Note that `.readline()` will keep the `\n` character and the `print` will append a newline which will make the output have "blank lines" between lines (note the post is tagged 3.x - so print should be a function here).

Comment: @JonClements. Fixed. I was going off of his code which shows the 2.x print statement, didn't look at the tag.

Comment: `f.readlines()` will consume the whole file, after that calls to `f.readline()` will just return the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

It is waiting for the first "Result" in the file and then prints the rest of the input:

```
import re, sys

bool = False
with open("input.txt", 'r+') as f:
    for line in f:
        if bool == True:
            sys.stdout.write(line)
        if re.search("Result",line):    #if it should match whole line, than it is also possible if "Result\n" == line: 
            bool = True
```

If you want end after first 3 prints, you may add variable `cnt = 0` and change this part of code (for example this way):

```
        if bool == True:
            sys.stdout.write(line)
            cnt = cnt+1
            if cnt == 3:
                break
```

Comment: He just wants to print next three lines. So this logic doesn't quite do what he wanted. Also, I think regular expressions are overkill for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('data', 'r') as f:
    lines = [ line.strip() for line in f]
    # get "Result" index
    ind = lines.index("Result")
    # get slice, add 4 since upper bound is non inclusive
    li = lines[ind:ind+4]
    print(li)
    ['Result', 'test1 : 12345', 'test2 : 23453', 'test3 : 2345454']

or as exercise with regex: 

import re  
with open('data', 'r') as f:

    text = f.read()
    # regex assumes that data as shown, ie, no blank lines between 'Result'
    # and the last needed line.
    mo =  re.search(r'Result(.*?\n){4}', text, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)

    print(mo.group(0))

Result

test1 : 12345

test2 : 23453

test3 : 2345454
```