# Printing the next line in Pycharm with Python 3.6.2

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to be able to print the next line in an opened text file provided the line prior starts with a certain string. The itertools method is not accomplishing what I'd like. Here is a sample of the text from which I'm printing:

Here is the other topic: [How to print next line in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33088234/how-to-print-next-line-in-python)

I want to print the line after any line that starts with "Password."
The itertools islice method does not seem to do much of anything, unless I'm mis-implementing it, nor does `print(next(op))`. (`op` is the name of my `open(filename)`).

Here is my full code:

```
def nonblank_lines(f):
    nonempty_lines = []
    for l in f:
        line = l.rstrip()
        if line:
            yield line.lstrip()

with open("C:\\Users\\MyName\\Desktop\\BLRP.txt", "r+") as op:
    for line in nonblank_lines(op):
        if line.startswith("Computer Name") or line.startswith("ERROR") or line.startswith("ID"):
            print(line)
        elif line.startswith("Password"):
            ***print(next(op))***
            #What do I do here?
    op.close()
```

Comment: `itertools` is part of the standard library. You don't need to install it. Unless you are using some custom build of Python?

Comment: Could you add some more description to the question ? I might suggest using `import re` and setting multiline mode (re.MULTILINE¶
), then just carefully constructing 1 pattern... a solution will be easier to present, with a bit more issue description

Comment: Oh, nice! Thanks! However, this function still is not printing the next line after the line starting with "Password."

Comment: Regardless, all you need is `print(next(f))`

Comment: That does not work either. See my edited post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("C:\\Users\\MyName\\Desktop\\BLRP.txt", "r+") as op:
    instance_of_generator = nonblank_lines(op)
    for line in instance_of_generator:
        if line.startswith("Computer Name") or line.startswith("ERROR") or line.startswith("ID"):
            print(line)
        elif line.startswith("Password"):
            print(next(instance_of_generator))
```

Comment: This did the trick! My "next" instance was referring to the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for this one. Cheers:

```
file = open("file","r+")
for line in file:
    if line.startswith("This"):
        print(file.readline())
file.close()
```

Comment: according to your description, you are asking for this thing, your code is doing something else.

Comment: Thank you for this! Even though I didn't use it, it's helpful to me!